# What is the difference between nodes, tasks, and cores in a SLURM scheduler?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, slurm, hpc

I am working on an HPC cluster using the R language. The particular partition I am able to send jobs to has 500Gb of RAM and ~50 cores.

When I send a job using a SLURM script, there are two options provided:

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
```

Meanwhile, my R script uses the `foreach` library to compute in parallel, like so:

```
cores = round(detectCores()/2) 
myCluster <- parallel::makeCluster(cores)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(myCluster)
```

When the SLURM `nodes` and `ntasks` options are both set to `1`, `detectCores()` still finds ~50 cores, and computing in parallel using a `foreach::foreach()` loop works. However, the parallelization does not greatly reduce computation time compared to my 8 core, 8Gb RAM personal computer. Is there efficiency to be gained by changing the `nodes` and `ntasks` options within the SLURM?

Comment: Regarding "When the SLURM nodes and ntasks options are both set to 1, detectCores() still finds ~50 cores": Use `parallelly::availableCores()` instead. It is designed to respect Slurm, and a lot of other environments that allocates a certain amount of resources to your R process. See https://parallelly.futureverse.org/#availablecores-vs-paralleldetectcores for more details

Comment: Re "cores = round(detectCores()/2)  ... However, the parallelization does not greatly reduce computation time compared to my 8 core, 8Gb RAM personal computer": If you're only asking for a single task, Slurm allocates only a single CPU core. Slurm will also restrict your job to a single CPU core, so, if you launch `cores = round(detectCores()/2)` (~50/2 cores), you'll have 25 parallel workers competing for a single core.  That's similar to you trying to launch 8*25=200 parallel workers on you 8-core laptop.

Comment: @HenrikB Wow. I was wondering why a 500Gb machine was running so slowly. This makes way more sense. Thank you!